# R save command's behavior depends on running enviroment (Rstudio vs command-line R)

Tags: r, command-line, save, rstudio

The size of the resulting output file depends if I run the same R script in Rstudio or R command-line.
Here is the script:

```
R.Version()
library(data.table)

sessionInfo()
l<-LETTERS
n<-seq(1,1e6)
d<-seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2018/1/1"), "days")

c1<-paste(n,d,l)
c2<-paste(d,l,n)
c3<-paste(l,n,d)

dt<-data.frame(a=c1,b=c2,c=c3)


save(dt,file="fileRstudio.Rdata")
#save(dt,file="fileRconsole.Rdata")
```

These are the size of the resulting files:
 23M fileRconsole.Rdata
 89M fileRstudio.Rdata

I want to kwow the origin of the diffence of this behavior and how to control it

The output of the sessionInfo() command is the same in both scenarios:

R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.1 tools_3.4.1

Comment: Your script prints `R.Version()` and `sessionInfo()`.  You should compare those results; they'll explain the difference.  It also attaches `data.table`, but never uses it. (When I run the script, I get an 18M file in R 3.4.4 that is identical in RStudio or the console.)

Comment: if I use the save option compress=FALSE, in the console enviroment the sizes of the files are the same.     
    save(dt,file="fileRconsole.Rdata",compress=FALSE)